# How to display a number as output value in node-editor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, mathematics

[image]

I would like to input a numeric value and output also a numeric value after it has gone through some nodes realizing a mathematical function.

I know how to realize the mathematical function with multiply and adding nodes (here: f(x)=x^2 + 5x ) but I do not know how to continue from the ADD-node on to display the output as a number.

Comment: Please submit a screen capture rather than a drawing.  Where do you want to display the output?  The console?  The 3D View?

Comment: I will change it, but I can not at the moment, cause Blender crashes everytime I try to make a screenshot by ctrl+F3.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred you can simply press the `Print Screen` button on your keyboard. How do you make the images in your questions? I like the style, and how it still conveys the meaning.

Comment: I took a photo of the picture drawn on a college block, opened it in Gimp, opened the curve editor , inverted the curve, so that black became white and vice versa and draw both endings closer to the middle. I did it because it seems to be better readable compared to the original photo.